# Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I keep getting this error on initial load of my application. I have searched high and low and the only thing I found to do was the code below in my context.

```
Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
```

I have this set in the OnModelCreating method but it is still throwing the error below:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'dbo.EdmMetadata'.
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.

Comment: It says *See the inner exception for details* - Did you do that using the debugger ?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to capture that exception because it is occurring on initial compile of Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5):

You should add this code in constructor of your `Context` class.